# How to set Gravity in Xamarin android programmatically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to place a linear layout at the centre.If I give padding the layout is moving, but if I set gravity as centre its not.Can I know why this happens and how to implement gravity.

I have attached the code I have used.

```
LinearLayout outerView = new LinearLayout(context);
outerView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
outerView.Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation.Vertical;
//outerView.setGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
outerView.SetPadding(70,10,10,10);
```

Comment: Why are you using the padding exactly?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change FillParent to WrapContent, so your container doesn't take all available space (if it does, then there's no point in setting the layout_gravity).

Secondly, by calling setGravity method, you're changing the way the children of given view are positioned. If you want to change how outerView is positioned in relation to it's parent, you should change it's layout_gravity. To do it, just specify the gravity when creating a LayoutParams for your outerView:

```
outerView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
{
    Gravity = GravityFlags.Center
}
```

Take a look at documentation of this class: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.LinearLayout+LayoutParams/